# Chmod ubuntu desktop fail

Tags: chmod

I accidentally did `chmod 667` on `/home/user/Desktop/` and now it is behaving strangely.

How can I reverse the damage I have done?

Comment: What is the exact command you executed? You can see the history using `history` or using the up arrow.

Comment: post the output of `history | tail -4` command.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: How can you know only four commands have been executed since?

Comment: it will be more accurate `history | tail -30 | grep chmod`

Comment: Close-voters: There's nothing unclear about this question, the desktop folder's permissions were changed to 667.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `chmod -x Desktop`, executing it from ~ ( your home folder).

Answer (score 4):

755 is standard mode for directories. just

```
 chmod 755 /home/User/Desktop
```

and everything will be ok